# Rendering knockout templates with JQM

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-mobile

I have this piece of code:

```
 <!--ko with: passengerDocs-->            
    <div data-bind="foreach: flights()">
     <div>
      <span data-bind="text: Carrier + Number"></span>
      <span data-bind="text: DepratureDateTime"></span>
      <span data-bind="text: Route"></span>
     </div>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

When i use it combined with Jquery mobile, the rendered HTML is:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: flights()"></div>
```

While without JQM reference I get the full above templated html.

Any idea?

Comment: _When i use it combined with Jquery mobile, the rendered HTML is:_? what?

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: Some thoughts: When using a foreach binding, you don't need the accessor `()` on your binding (so `foreach: flights()` should be `foreach: flights`), but when using logic in your binding, you *do*. Meaning `data-bind="text: Carrier + Number"` should be `data-bind="text: Carrier() + Number()"` (Assuming Carrier and Number are observables and not standard properties)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JSFiddle that is my best interpretation of what you're trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/NuaKf/2/

```
<!--ko with: passengerDocs-->     
<button data-bind="click: fillFlights">Fill Flights</button>
<div data-bind="foreach: flights">
 <div>
  <span data-bind="text: Carrier() + Number()"></span> - 
  <span data-bind="text: DepartureDateTime"></span> - 
  <span data-bind="text: Route"></span>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Some thoughts:

1. When using a foreach binding, you don't need the accessor () on your binding (so foreach: flights() should be foreach: flights),
2. When using logic in your binding, you do. Meaning data-bind="text: Carrier + Number" should be data-bind="text: Carrier() + Number()" (Assuming Carrier and Number are observables and not standard properties)
3. You don't seem to have anything in here specific to jQuery Mobile, so it's not clear what error you would be receiving because of it, but you should use the console to view them, to help clarify the issue.

If you can clarify the problem, I can make my answer more specific to your problem.